# Not able to install Gopls in VSCode due to Permission issues

Tags: linux, go, visual-studio-code, gopls

After installing Golang and setting up the GOPATH in `.bashrc`, I am not able to install the Gopls and other tools that VSCode requires to be installed.

When I am clicking the `Install` button in the VSCode popup, it fails to install stating permission issues. On going through the error logs, I see that VSCode is trying to install the packages to the `GOBIN` directory which is set to `/user/local/bin`. This directory by default is read-only, therefore the installation is failing.

I can solve this issue by using the Linux terminal by installing the packages with `sudo`. But that's not the point. I want to fix the issue within VSCode itself.

I know it's not a Golang issue, but something related to Linux.

Answer (score 1):

The issue can be fixed by unsetting the `GOBIN` env variable by:

```
go env -w GOBIN=''
```

You can cross-check all the go env by: `go env`

On restarting the VSCode and clicking the "Install" button in the pop-up, the packages are installed in the `GOPATH`, which is an editable directory.